# iphone hostingView does not fit parent view

Tags: iphone, view, core-plot

I have some problems with the layout of my core plot graph.
To be more precise, I have created a GraphViewController (.h, .m and associated nib file). In the nib file I have added another UIView. This embedded view will be used to set the graph (as I do not want it to use the whole view). I then need to create a hosting view  from this embedded view.
The embedded view is named graphView, I first though I needed to get the frame representing the graphView and create the hostingView so the graph will fit in the graphView. When I use the:
    CPHostingLayerView *hostingView = [[CPHostingLayerview alloc] initWithFrame: [graphView frame]]
...

it does not work as expected, the graph does not fit the view (it is bigger than the graphView I created in IB)

Hope I am clear :(
Any idea would be more than welcome.
thanks a lot,
Luc

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123373/iphone-hostingview-does-not-fit-parent-view and is possibly a posting glitch.

Comment: thanks a lot, I have deleted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find an answer :) Instead of adding an UIView within IB and programmatically create a CPLayerHostingView, I directly declared the view as an CPLayerHostingView in IB, that works perfectly.
Regards,
Luc

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with the same issue. What worked for me is a simpler way :
In super-view (where you are adding the core plot graph as a subview), add this code:
[self.subview.graphHostingView setFrame:self.view.bounds];

where subview is the view with the core-plot graph. And add this code 'after' you have done the graph initialization in the sub-view.